# BroadcastReceiver's "onReceive" method is never Called

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I'm setting up an inner `BroadcastReceiver` to get activity transitions Updates such as walking, in_Vehicle. But the `onReceive` method is never called.

`onCreate`

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Intent intent = new Intent(TRANSITIONS_RECEIVER_ACTION);
        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);

        mTransitionsReceiver = new TransitionsReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mTransitionsReceiver, new IntentFilter(TRANSITIONS_RECEIVER_ACTION));

        mLogFragment = (LogFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.log_fragment);
    }

setupActivityTransitions();
```

`setupActivityTransitions()` method

```
    ActivityTransitionRequest request = new ActivityTransitionRequest(transitions);
        // Register for Transitions Updates.
        Task<Void> task =
                ActivityRecognition.getClient(this)
                        .requestActivityTransitionUpdates(request, mPendingIntent);
        task.addOnSuccessListener(
                new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Transitions Api was successfully registered.");
                    }
                });
        task.addOnFailureListener(
                new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Transitions Api could not be registered: " + e);
                    }
                });
```

`BroadcastReceiver`

```
public class TransitionsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("@2345","dfhudfdf");
            if (!TextUtils.equals(TRANSITIONS_RECEIVER_ACTION, intent.getAction())) {
                mLogFragment.getLogView()
                        .println("Received an unsupported action in TransitionsReceiver: action="
                                + intent.getAction());
                return;
            }
            if (ActivityTransitionResult.hasResult(intent)) {
                ActivityTransitionResult result = ActivityTransitionResult.extractResult(intent);
                for (ActivityTransitionEvent event : result.getTransitionEvents()) {
                    String activity = toActivityString(event.getActivityType());
                    String transitionType = toTransitionType(event.getTransitionType());
                    mLogFragment.getLogView()
                            .println("Transition: "
                                    + activity + " (" + transitionType + ")" + "   "
                                    + new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.US)
                                    .format(new Date()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you registered receiver in the manifest?                                                
      `<receiver android:name="packagename.TransitionsReceiver " />` ?

Comment: for BroadcastReceiver  class , you must have to register your receiver in your manifest which broadcast your activity on which you want to gets notified. Have you register it in Manifest class ?

Comment: `<receiver 
    android:name=".your_package_name.YOUR_BRAODCAST_CLASSNAME" 
    >
      <intent-filter>
                <action 
      android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_YOU_WANT_TO_LISTEN"> 
                </action>
       </intent-filter>
 </receiver>`

Comment: I have created my BroadcastReceiver class as a inner class of mainActivity. Should I register my BroadcastReceiver class in the manifest even if it is a inner class??? @Kamran Ali

Comment: yes you are using BroadCastReceiver class for that you have to register it in your manifest, if your use case is within the app extend your class with LocalBroadCast receiver only in this case you don't need to register it, and you can simply register or unregister it on Attach or detach of fragment if you are using fragment if activity use onCreate and on destroy. **If still there's any thing you don't understand please let me know I'll share a code snippet for you.**

Answer (score 1):

For getting your `onReceive()` called, you will have to add these -

- add your BroadcastReceiver to into **manifest**, in this way -

  `<receiver android:name="YourReceiver"> <intent-filter> <action android:name="YourAction" /> </intent-filter> </receiver>`
- call `registerReceiver()` in your activity.
  Also, don't forget to call `unegisterReceiver()` to avoid leaks.

Comment: I have created my BroadcastReceiver class as a inner class of mainActivity. Should I register my BroadcastReceiver class in the manifest even if it is a inner class???

Comment: No, in that case registration in manifest won't be required. It should work, just try changing your `TRANSITIONS_RECEIVER_ACTION`  to something else. I suspect the issue might be because of https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts

Comment: no matters you use it as inner class or separate class , if you are using BraodCast class you must have to register it in your manifest to listen any activity you want.

Comment: Agreed, just checked registering in manifest is not necessary for implicit broadcast but required for custom/explicit broadcasts.

Answer (score 0):

you have to register you Receiver in the manifest with the action you want :

```
   <receiver android:name=".Your_receiver_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="THE_ACTION_NAME"
                    android:exported="false"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: I have created my BroadcastReceiver class as a inner class of mainActivity. Should I register my BroadcastReceiver class in the manifest even if it is a inner class???

Comment: try to create a Broad receiver separately

Comment: Nothing changed